# Error Build Failed-Cordova windows 8

Tags: android, cordova, window

While trying to build a project I got this error
I was  following [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html) ,everything seemed fine till
"cordova build".

I've tried to downgrade node and many other solutions suggested in some similar questions but I've had no luck.

```
OS: Windows 8.1 x64  
Cordova v 5.1.1   
Ant version 1.9.4
Node v0.12.7
npm 2.11.3
```

Android sdk and Java are probably installed and added to Environment variables PATH 
also sdk/tools and /platform-tools are also included in PATH

Error

```
C:\Users\user-\dua>cordova build
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\user-\dua\platforms\android\cordova\build.
bat""

ANDROID_HOME=C:\android-sdk-win
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
Running: C:\Users\user-\dua\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\
user-\dua\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user-\dua\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 185



What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Invalid revision: 23.0.0.3

 Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.269 secs

C:\Users\user-\dua\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^

Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Users\user-\dua\platforms\and
roid\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\user-\dua\platforms\android\build.gradle
-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```